# OAS 10g -10.1.2.3.0 forms and reports server, opmn.log is not getting updated

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Hi Can you tell which way to drive the analysis for my issue opmn.log is not getting updated. All the instances are working fine and individual instances logs are getting updated but $ORACLE_HOME/opmn/logs/opmn.log is always 0kb since a week time. I could not find any statements reg opmn.log on opmn.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference in Logging mechanism between (9.0.2 to 10.1.2) and (10.1.3 to later).

> (9.0.2 to 10.1.2) log-file path="x" level="x" rotation-size="x" 
>   (10.1.3 to later) log path="x" comp="x;y;z" rotation-size="x"

**(9.0.2 to 10.1.2) :**

*ORACLE_HOME/opmn/logs/ipm.log:*

Review the error codes and messages that are shown in the ipm.log file. The PM portion of OPMN generates and outputs the error messages in this file. The ipm.log file tracks command execution and operation progress. The level of detail that gets logged in the ipm.log can be modified by configuration in the opmn.xml file. Refer to Chapter 3, "opmn.xml Common Configuration" for examples of debug levels.

*ORACLE_HOME/opmn/logs/ons.log:*

Use the ons.log file to debug the ONS portion of OPMN or for early OPMN errors. The ONS portion of OPMN is initialized before PM, and so errors that occur early in OPMN initialization will show up in the ons.log file.

*ORACLE_HOME/opmn/logs/opmn.log:*

*The opmn.log file contains output generated by OPMN when the ipm.log and ons.log files are not available.* Typically, the only output written to the opmn.log file will be the exit status of a child OPMN process. A status code of 4 indicates a normal reload of OPMN. All other status codes indicate an abnormal termination of the child OPMN process.

**ipm.log(10.1.2) similar to opmn.log(10.1.3)**
**ons.log(10.1.2) similar to opmn.dbg(10.1.3)**